# Dynamic binding from input (Thymeleaf) field to list of values parameter

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I am trying to get my head into Thymeleaf and some form that are still quite simple, but am not able to get this to work...

I have a business object which stores some values that are classified by an enum (internal implementation is not in scope of this question):

```
public class MyBusObj {
   public static enum MY_TYPE {A, B, C };
   
   public int getValue( MY_TYPE type ) { ... }
   public void setValue( MY_TYPE type, int value ) { ... }
}
```

When I pass an instance of that object to my model like
'model.addAttribute( "myBusObj", new MyBusObj() );'
it arrives at the template level and I can access all internally available values like this (showTypes is basically MY_TYPE or a subset of it as array):

```
<td th:each="type : ${showTypes}">
   <input type="number" th:value="${myBusObj.getValue( type )}" th:field="${myBusObj.setValue( type )}"/>
</td>
```

It displays a line of edit boxes, one for each value. That's what I want to achieve and it's dynamic, for if I add more types, a new box for type 'D' will show up automatically, that's perfect.

While the direction from business object -> view works perfectly as 'getValue( type )' results in the correct value the part 'th:field="${myBusObj.setValue( type )}"' obviously can't work as it must be something like '(type, value)', but I can't write 'myBusObj.value( type )' either.

Can anyone think of a solution of how to write the user input back into the business object? Otherwise I must think of a "crutch" like restructure my business object.

Thanks in advance,
Stephan

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to find a way to handle enum using Thymeleaf. The correct syntax to access enum values (say in a dropdown, for example) you need to use it like this:

```
<option th:each="myitem : ${T(your.package.YourEnum).values()}"

th:value="${myitem.name()}" th:text="${myitem.name()}"></option>
```

Similarly, you can do it in for-each for `<td>` like below:

```
<td th:each="type : ${T(your.package.YourEnum).values()}">
  ......
</td>
```

Hoping you got the idea. Take a look at [here](https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringBootFlashy/blob/master/src/main/resources/templates/profileappuser.html) and [here](https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringBootFlashy/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/boot/rocks/model/AppUserProfileSkills.java) for a comprehensive example.

**Update:**

Got it. In that case you have to make use of rowStat provided by Thymeleaf where you can track the iteration.

> But make sure you have the field in your bean as a Collection type "AND"
> should have size matching your enum object.

Then you can do something like below:

```
<td> <select th:name="${yourbeanobj.beanFieldCollection[__${rowStat.index}__].beanFiled}" th:field="${yourbeanobj.beanFieldCollection[__${rowStat.index}__].beanFiled}" th:errorclass="is-invalid" multi>
<option value="abc">Iterate Your Enum List Here</option>
</select>
</td>
```

Not exact match for your requirement but you can take a look at a similar example [here](https://github.com/ajkr195/ThymeleafDynamicFields) and [here](https://github.com/ajkr195/ThymeleafDynamicFields/blob/master/src/main/resources/templates/index.html).

Comment: Hi Ajay, that's not really the issue. Reading the enum out is no problem at all. But I want to use the single enum value as a parameter to write the value from an input element back to the bean (see frame for business object at top, "setValue()".

Comment: Updated my answer Stephan. Try that and share the outcome.

Comment: Hi Ajay, thanks a lot for your efforts! I have seen these concepts before, but it does not really touch the issue I face:
Your code line writes the value of the input field using this assignment:
th:field="${yourbeanobj.beanFieldCollection[__${rowStat.index}__].beanFiled}"
That's exactly the point, I don't have a "beanField". I would have to write something like
th:field="${yourbeanobj.beanFiled( beanFieldCollection[__${rowStat.index}__], value )}"
But then I can't explicitly access the "value" (data the user entered into the input field).

Comment: I come to the idea that it is really not possible to do it this way. And I have to develop a way around. Like not writing back to the bean but into "native" fields or explicitly coding beanFields for all values from the collection or so. I do have ideas for alternatives but they are all not very elegant.